# Switch Pages In WPF using MahApps

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

First of all, thank you for taking your time to read this.
Im pretty new to WPF and especially to using MahApps - http://mahapps.com

Im having problems switching between pages that I have created using MahApps in my window.

Here is my starting window (MainWindow):

```
<Window
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
                  xmlns:Dialogs="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;assembly=MahApps.Metro" x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
                  xmlns:Dialog="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
                  Dialog:DialogParticipation.Register="{Binding}"
                  Title="MainWindow"
                  Height="600"
                  Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Frame x:Name="Main"/>
</Grid>
```

Here is the page that I want to move to (I created a frame in the main so I could put the content of this page on it):

```
<Controls:MetroWindow
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
                  xmlns:Dialogs="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;assembly=MahApps.Metro" x:Class="WpfApplication.MainMenu"
                  xmlns:Dialog="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
                  Dialog:DialogParticipation.Register="{Binding}"
                  Title="MainMenu"
                  Height="600"
                  Width="800" NonActiveBorderBrush="#FFC32C2C">
<Grid>

    <Image x:Name="Background" Source="C:\Users\User\Desktop\Iddo Work\C#Learning\WpfApplication/teaserBackground.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill">
        <Image.BitmapEffect>
            <BlurBitmapEffect Radius="17" />
        </Image.BitmapEffect>
    </Image>
    <Image x:Name="Logo" Source="C:\Users\User\Desktop\Iddo Work\C#Learning\WpfApplication/Trivia.png" Margin="0,60,0,320" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="Username" Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="       USERNAME" Margin="0,308,0,226" Width="200" Height="35" TextAlignment="Justify" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <TextBox x:Name="Password" Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="       PASSWORD" Margin="0,378,0,156" Width="200" Height="35" TextAlignment="Justify" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" />
    <Button x:Name="SignIn" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="407,435,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" Height="80" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}" Click="SignIn_Click">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\User\Desktop\Iddo Work\C#Learning\WpfApplication/signIn.png"/>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="SignUp" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="310,435,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" Height="80" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}" Click="SignUp_Click">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\User\Desktop\Iddo Work\C#Learning\WpfApplication/sign-add-icon.png"/>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>

</Grid>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sure thing. Added some of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer: 
Frames themselves are meant to load pages and your menu item is inheriting from a window so that will never work.

Here are the mods you need to make:

1. In your MainWindow.xaml change the Window tag to Controls:MetroWindow (like you have in your MainMenu xaml
2. In your MainWindow.xaml.cs remove the base class reference for the MainWindow (MainWindow : Window becomes just MainWindow)
3. In your MainMenu.xaml change Controls:MetroWindow to just UserControl
4. Back in your MainWindow.xaml, add a ref to your namespace xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WhateverHere"
5. In MainWindow.xaml, remove the  and add your control directly instead

MainWindow.xaml

```
    <Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="WPFDeleteMe.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
            xmlns:Dialogs="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
            xmlns:Dialog="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
            xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WPFDeleteMe"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="700" Width="900">
        <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
            <my:MainMenu></my:MainMenu>
        </Grid>
    </Controls:MetroWindow>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

MainMenu.xaml

```
    <UserControl x:Class="WPFDeleteMe.MainMenu"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="800">
        <Grid>
            <Image x:Name="Background" Source="d:\images\doll-161405_960_720.png" Stretch="UniformToFill">
                <Image.BitmapEffect>
                    <BlurBitmapEffect Radius="17" />
                </Image.BitmapEffect>
            </Image>
            <Image x:Name="Logo" Source="d:\images\Carestream_Solutions.gif" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="150" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Button x:Name="SignIn" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="407,435,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" Height="80" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}" Click="SignIn_Click">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="d:\images\war_kitten.jpg"/>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="SignUp" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="310,435,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" Height="80" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}" Click="SignUp_Click">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="d:\images\war_kitten.jpg"/>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I have tried this method but unfortunately I receive this message: http://prntscr.com/fs9g7p

Comment: I think its caused because the MainMenu is a <Controls:MetroWindow> type and not a regular <Page>.... Not sure how to solve it

Comment: Looking at a project I did with mahapps before for reference now, updating answer.

Comment: Thank you! Could I use the MahApps controls in the usercontrols?

Comment: Absolutely, you just need to add the references to the mahapps controls in your user control xaml. If my answer solved your issue, please don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer for future reference for other users.